# How to protect ServeStaticModule module in NestJS with a Guard

Tags: express, authentication, nestjs, static-files

I have a folder with static files that I want to serve with Nest's `ServeStaticModule` but I want to protect it with one of the guards that I have.

Is it possible with NestJS style, or the only option is to hang an `express` middleware with `app.use()` in the `bootstrap()` function?